# make folder netbeans project and ftp upload

Tags: netbeans, ide

I've just downloaded netBeans 7.2 and an [ftp plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39197/ftpsitedeployer). I would like to be able to make a folder (html, css, javascript, php) on my computer (which I made in eclipse) a NetBeans 'project' (at least that's what I think I want to do). Then, on save, upload to the remote directory online. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run - Set Project Configuration - Customize
Click Manage next to Remote Connection..

I guess you can figure out the rest..